# Using StaxEventItemReader with jaxb2 unmarshaller

Tags: java, jaxb, spring-batch, stax

I have xml that looks like this

```
<Items>
  <Item>
  <Item>
</Items>
```

And i have xsd for this structure and have generated coresponding class using xjc (so `Items` is rootElement)

problem is that `StaxEventItemReader` needs a way to unmarshall just `<Item></Item>` and take it as root element, so jaxb2 unmarshallers throws error that it expects Items but got Item.

Comment: You can publish the relevant XSD rules, exception stack trace and JAXB-related piece of code? Also I remove `spring-batch` tag, as you question has no direct relation with this framework.

Comment: Ops, sorry for retagging: I was wrong. After reading again I think I've got the problem. You need to use `StaxEventItemReader.setFragmentRootElementName("Item")` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Problem](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10282) solved in spring-oxm 3.2.3.